# SQL Average of a column until certain point in time

Tags: sql

I want to calculate the average time each users takes to cancel a loan from all previous loans, and how many loans he took up until a certain point in time.

Let's suppose I have this table with the id of each customer, the day of the loan and the time it takes the user to cancel the loan.

```
ID  date       time
1   17/7/2018   8    
1   7/8/2018    18
2   21/12/2018  0
2   22/12/2018  5
2   31/12/2018  5
```

I would expect this result

```
ID  date       AVG(time) n_loans
1   17/7/2018   8         0
1   7/8/2018    13        1
2   21/12/2018  0         0
2   22/12/2018  2.5       1
2   31/12/2018  3.33      2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please tag a database (Oracle, MySQL, etc)

Comment: Homework? Did you try anything by your self?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a running average:

```
select id, date, time,
       avg(time) over (partition by id order by date) as avg_time,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as n_loans
from t;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?  As the OP, you can do this, but leaving a comment helps everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, as you didn't mention the dbms I tried the in general for almost all dbms way as via join

```
    Select * from ( 
      ( Select id,date,count(*)
        from table group by id,date) t1 
           JOIN
        (SELECT AVG(TIME)
          FROM TABLE
         GROUP BY ID  ) t2
          ON 
        t1.ID =t2.id )
```